# unsupported configuration: hda-duplex not supported in this QEMU binary

Tags: sound, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to create a virtual machine using virtual machine manager.(KVM)
following this [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/117635/how-to-install-kvm-and-create-virtual-machines-on-ubuntu/) . I have reached up to step 5.

[image]

Then I clicked finish button. And I saw this error:

[image]

I tried this process a few times, faced same error at same point.
Any idea to get rid of this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Restart libvirt-bin

```
sudo stop libvirt-bin
sudo start libvirt-bin
```

Now Reopen virt-manager and try again, I hope problem is solved